# Strict atoi/strtol function

Tags: c, type-conversion

In C when I use:

```
int x = 0;
char str[] = " \t123abc";
x = atoi(str);
printf("%d\n", str); //123
```

`123` is printed. I would like to know if there is a 'strict' C function that returns 0 if the string isn't fully an integer. (I don't care about the number sign (always positive) and the base (always 10)).

Some examples:

```
" \t123abc" -> 0
" 123abc" -> 0
"123abc" -> 0
" 123 " -> 0
"123" -> 123
"123\n" -> 0
```

Currently I created a `int sstoi (char *str)` function to do it:

```
static const unsigned int pow10[10] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000};

int sstoi (char *str) {
    int result = 0, length = strlen(str);
    char c;
    if (length > 10) return 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {   
        c = str[i];
        if (c < 48 || c > 57) return 0;
        result += (c-48)*pow10[length-i-1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

I believe that it should be improved: can someone help me out?

Comment: No need to use powers of 10. Just go `result = result * 10 + (c - '0')`. And it is better not to use magic numbers, note I used `'0'`. The `length > 10` constraint is too loose, as the value can still overflow 32-bits.

Comment: Use `strtol()`.  Check that the string isn't empty and has no leading whitespace, then let `strtol()` set a pointer to the first invalid character -- if it points to the terminating null, the whole string was good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can at first check if all characters in string are number then use atoi:

```
if(strspn(str, "0123456789") == strlen(str))
{
   x = atoi(str);
}
else
{
  x = 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this loop over every char for `strspn`, `strlen` and `atoi`, making 3 loops against the 2 loops (`strlen` and `for`) in my method? Wouldn't this method be a bit slower for 'big' ints? Just asking, as I'm just trying to learn how to improve efficiency in my code :)

Comment: `str[strspn(str, "0123456789")] == 0` avoids the `strlen`.

Answer (score 3):

`strtol()` can set a pointer to the first invalid character in the string it scans, which would be the first character after the number.  If you check that the first character is valid, you can use this pointer to see whether there were characters following the number or not.

```
int sstoi(char *s) { 
    char *ep; // to point to first char after the number

    if (isdigit(*s)) { // make sure first char is a digit

        // convert, and find first invalid char
        int x = strtol(s, &ep, 10); 

        // return conversion if first invalid char was the
          // terminating null
        if (!(*ep)) 
            return x;
    } 
    return 0; // otherwise return 0
}
```

Comment: This looks mostly right, but I'd suggest two caveats. First, you get implementation-defined behavior if the result from strtol doesn't fit in an int (it returns `long int`). Second is that `strtol` returns LONG_MAX or LONG_MIN if the value is out of range of a long int, which may or may not be the intended behavior here.

Comment: (I suppose also that `sstoi` should be const-correct, ie take a `const char *`)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an inbuilt function which directly returns 0, it the input is wrong.

You can use the inbuilt function `isdigit(char s)` to check whether the given input is valid and if it's not then you can return 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 

bool isValidNumber(char digitsArray[]){
    bool isNumber = true;
    for(int i=0; i < strlen(digitsArray); i++){
        if(!isdigit(digitsArray[i])){
            isNumber = false;
            break;
        }
    } 
    return isNumber;
}

int getNumber(char digitsArray[]){
    if(isValidNumber(digitsArray)){
        return atoi(digitsArray);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "123\n";
    int number = getNumber(str);
    printf("Number is %d", number);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: The `isValidNumber` won't work if the char[] array contains a negative number.

Comment: `isValidNumber` is accidentally quadratic in runtime, and exhibits undefined behavior if `digitsArray` contains any negative values (because of `isdigit`).

Comment: Hey @PaulHankin, thanks for explaining the cases where the code fails.